# Cross origin ajax request with Phonegap on Android

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

Building an app using Phonegap and jquery on Android using this code to request xml data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(xml) {
        //Retrieve user token
        var token = $(xml).find('token').text(); // Store token for subsequent requests
        alert("Token is " + token);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert("Error");
        xml = xhr.responseXML;
        $(xml).find('error').each(function() {
            alert($(this).find('message').text());
        });
    }
});
```

I'll ultimately be making a REST request to an api, but checking this way with a static file to try and figure out the issue.

This works fine on a handset using Android 2.3.4 when requesting the file from both a local and remote location. An error occurs when making the remote (ie. cross origin) request on a newer device using Android 3.2.1.

Is this because of a tighter security policy in the more recent browser? If so, and suggestions how I can address this?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for this solution that i posted earlier, it had worked for me. you can give it a try.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164136/load-jquery-mobile-page-from-different-domain/12171043#12171043)

Comment: Thanks. This might bring forth a smile (?!) - I actually found this was caused on this particular device as it was dropping the wi-fi connection. Moral: check the basics first!